# DbParameter on Oracle: No replacement

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, asp.net-mvc-4

I can't seem to find an answer to this, so here I am. I want my application run on MySQL, SQL Server an Oracle, so I used DbConnection to abstract the database. It seems to work fine on MySQL and SQL Server, but when I try to run on Oracle, the parameters are not replaced before the request is sent to the server.

Here is the code: (connection is an instance of DbConnection, seems to be no problem with it)

```
    public DbDataReader ExecuteQuery(string _query, Dictionary<string, object> _params)
    {
        DbDataReader dataReader;
        DbCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand();

        cmd.CommandText = _query;
        if (_params != null)
        {
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> param in _params)
            {
                DbParameter parameter = cmd.CreateParameter();
                parameter.ParameterName = param.Key;
                parameter.Value = param.Value;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(parameter);
            }
        }

        dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess);

        return (dataReader);
    }
```

And the caller of this (ugly, but just for test purpose)

```
        Dictionary<string, object> _params = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        _params.Add("fd", DateTime.Now);
        _params.Add("c", 293);
        DbDataReader reader = db.ExecuteQuery("SELECT p.ID as PID, p.NAME as PNAME FROM USER AS p WHERE p.SUBCRIPTION_DATE > @sd AND p.FK_COUNTRY = @c", _params);
```

I tried by writing :fd and :c instead of @fd and @c, and it doesn't work either. The error I'm receiving from Oracle is: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to set `BindByName` property on Oracle to make it work. Else replacing only works on `:1`, `:2`, etc.

I use this code myself to set `BindByName` since I have written a DB independent query engine. It uses reflection to get the property name:

```
var oracleCommandBindByNameProperty = command.GetType().GetProperty("BindByName");
oracleCommandBindByNameProperty.SetValue(command, true, null);
```

Comment: Ok, so I need to cast my DbCommand to an OracleCommand to have acces to BindByName property. Problem is I don't have acces to OracleCommand class. So either I add the reference, or I change my query generator to write positions instead of aliases. Thank you for the quick answer.

Answer (score 0):

In C# using **ODP.NET** by example:

```
if (cmd is Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleCommand)
{                    
    ((Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleCommand)cmd).BindByName = true;
}
```